# Facing issue while upgrading React Version 15.6.2 to 16.6.3

Tags: reactjs, react-16

Upgrading react version from 15.6.2 to 16.2.0.

But facing below issues while running build of the application,

> ERROR in ../node_modules/react-addons-update/index.js [INFO] Module
>   not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react/lib/update' in
>   'D:\Projects\MyTask\web\node_modules\react-addons-update' [INFO]  @
>   ../node_modules/react-addons-update/index.js 1:17-44

**package.json**
"react": "^16.6.3",
"react-dom": "^16.6.3"

Can you help me out with the solution on the above problem ?

Answer (score 0):

React 16 no longer uses react/lib/* https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/09/26/react-v16.0.html#packaging.